# Heroku SSL redirect to www.example.com with AWS Route 53 and Cloudfront

Tags: ssl, amazon-route53, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

### Current Situation

> `example.com` == `examplecom` and so on because of spam

I've a Domain `examplecom` on GoDaddy and a SSL cert for it. The real application is hosted on Heroku at `exampleherokuappcom`. I also uploaded the SSL cert on heroku via this guide: [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl).

I want that the url always appends `www.` that you'll never access the 'naked' domain.

I use **AWS Route 53** with the following Records:

- `[A]` from `examplecom` to `examples3bucket` (the s3bucket is just
  a redirect to wwwexamplecom)
- `[CNAME]` from `wwwexamplecom` to `wwwexamplecomherokudnscom`

### Problem

If I access `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com` everything works (I get always redirected to `https://www.example.com`). But If I open `https://example.com` you don't get redirected which is a known Problem with the s3buckets and route 53 because it can't handle https (that's what I read):

> S3 won’t allow you to configure an SSL certificate, so you cannot easily use Route 53 to redirect your root domain in HTTPS. If you need to do this, consider using a DNS provider that offers CNAME/ALIAS records root domains. For more information see the Custom domains Dev Center article, or [this blog post](http://building.vts.com/blog/2015/11/02/route53-ssl-naked-domain-redirect/), which shows how to set up a SSL naked domain redirect. *Source: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53 (sorry I am not allowed to post more than 2 links)*

### My approach

The Blogpost from above was actually pretty helpful. So I've set up `Cloudfront` but it didn't work for me because I don't know what I should use as `SSL Endpoint` for heroku because I don't have one (I use the free of charge Heroku SSL). If I type `heroku certs -a example` I get:

Name | Common Name(s) | Expires | Trusted | Type

namedid-12345 | wwwexamplecom, examplecom | 2018-02-22 06:35 UTC | True | SNI

but no 'real' endpoint. Is probably `www.example.com.heorkudns.com` my endpoint?

In Route 53 I have a

- `[A]` Record from `example.com` to `<id-of-cloudfront>.cloudfront.net`
- Do I need also a `CNAME`?

### Update 0

After days of research I couldn't find a way to do it with Cloudfront and Route53. Therefore, I switched to **DNsimple**. They provide an easy one click function for Heroku SSL. It took me about 5 minutes to

- create an account
- deposit the credit card
- change the nameserver of my domain to point to DNsimple instead of Route 53
- Copy my MX Records (don't forget them)
- Set up Heroku SSL

After that it took about 2 hours (it can take up to 24 hours) until everything was active.

Now all domains get redirected to `https://www.example.com`

The only "bad" point of this solution is, that it costs minimum 5€ per month where cloudfront and route 53 would be cheaper.

Comment: Your update sounds suspiciously like an answer.